# trigger tab completion for python batch process built around readline

Tags: python, batch-file, command-line-interface, stdin, readline

**Background:** I have a python program that imports and uses the readline module to build a homemade command line interface.  I have a second python program (built around bottle, a web micro-framework) that acts as a front-end for that CLI.  The second python program opens a pipe-like interface to the first, essentially passing user input and CLI output back and forth between the two.

**Problem:** In the outer wrapper program (the web interface), whenever the end-user presses the TAB key (or any other key that I bind the readline completer function), that key is inserted into the CLI's stdin **without** firing the readline completer function.  I need this to trigger readline's command completion function instead, as normally occurs during an interactive CLI session.

**Possible Solution #1:** Is there some way to send the TAB key to a subprocess' stdin, so that a batch usage works the same as an interactive usage?

**Possible Solution #2:** Or, if there was some way to trigger the entire completion process manually (including matches **generation** and **display**), I could insert and scan for a special text sequence, like `"<TAB_KEY_HERE>"`, firing the possible completion matches **display** function manually.  (I wrote the completer function, which generates the possible matches, so all I really need is access to readline's function to display the possible matches.)

**Possible Solution #3:**  I guess, if I cannot access readline's matches-display function, the last option is to rewrite readline's built-in display-completion function, so I can call it directly.  :(

Is there a better solution?  Any suggestions on following the paths presented by any of the above solutions?  I am stuck on #1 and #2, and I'm trying to avoid #3.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution #1** proved to be a workable approach.  The key was to **not** connect the web socket directly to the CLI app.  Apparently, readline was falling back into some simpler mode, which filtered out all TAB's, since it was not connected to a real PTY/TTY.  (I may not be remembering this exactly right.  Many cobwebs have formed.)  Instead, a PTY/TTY pair needed to be opened and inserted in between the CLI app and web-sockets app, which tricked the CLI app into thinking it was connected to a real keyboard-based terminal, like so:

```
import pty
masterPTY, slaveTTY = pty.openpty()
appHandle = subprocess.Popen(
    ['/bin/python', 'myapp.py'],
    shell=False,
    stdin=slaveTTY,
    stdout=slaveTTY,
    stderr=slaveTTY,
    )
...
while True
    # read output from CLI app
    output = os.read(masterPTY, 1024)
    ...
    # write output to CLI app
    while input_data:
        chars_written = os.write(masterPTY, input_data)
        input_data = input_data[chars_written:]
    ...
appHandle.terminate()
os.close(masterPTY)
os.close(slaveTTY)
```

HTH someone else.  :)

See this answer to a related question for more background:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14565848/538418