# how to send tab-key to python subprocess's stdin

Tags: python, subprocess, readline, tab-completion

**Background:**  I have a Python subprocess that connects to a shell-like application, which uses the readline library to handle input, and that app has a TAB-complete routine for command input, just like bash.  The child process is spawned, like so:

```
def get_cli_subprocess_handle():
    return subprocess.Popen(
                            '/bin/myshell',
                            shell=False,
                            stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                            )
```

Everything works great, except tab-complete.  Whenever my Python program passes the tab character, `'\t'` to the subprocess, I get 5 spaces in the STDIN, instead of triggering the readline library's tab-complete routine.  :(

**Question:**  What can I send to the subprocess's STDIN to trigger the child's tab-complete function?  Maybe asked another way:  How do I send the TAB ***key*** as opposed to the TAB ***character***, if that is even possible?

**Related but Unanswered and Derailed:**

[trigger tab completion for python batch process built around readline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12378473/trigger-tab-completion-for-python-batch-process-built-around-readline)

Comment: Probably this is not an answer (of course, is not the adequate solution), but, why don't you check if the input are 5 consecutive spaces?. Probably the sequence escape \t is captured by your shell and translated into 5 spaces

Comment: @Manuel - Actually, I am injecting the `'\t'` myself via an re.sub(), so I know it is not 5 spaces.  Thanks for double-checking!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shell like application is probably differentiating between a terminal being connected to stdin and a pipe being connected to it. Many Unix utilities do just that to optimise their buffering (line vs. block) and shell-like utilities are likely to disable command completion facilities on batch input (i.e. PIPE) to avoid unexpected results. Command completion is really an interactive feature which requires a terminal input.

Check out the `pty` module and try using a master/slave pair as the pipe for your subprocess.

Comment: Thanks, isedev!  I connected through a masterPTY, slaveTTY via the pty.openpty() method, and then I was able to send the tab-key per my requirements. ... I added an answer below, detailing the application of your suggestion to my case.

Answer (score 2):

There really is no such thing as sending a tab **key** to a pipe. A pipe can only accept strings of bits, and if the tab character isn't doing it, there may not be a solution.

There is a project that does something similar called [pexpect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect). Just looking at its `interact()` code, I'm not seeing anything obvious that makes it work and yours not. Given that, the most likely explanation is that pexpect actually does some work to make itself look like a pseudo-terminal. Perhaps you could incorporate its code for that?

Comment: Thanks, Ken!  The pexpect project was indeed helpful, and your explanation was correct.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [isedev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14565848/538418), I modified my code as follows:

```
import os, pty

def get_cli_subprocess_handle():
    masterPTY, slaveTTY = pty.openpty()
    return masterPTY, slaveTTY, subprocess.Popen(
                                                 '/bin/myshell',
                                                 shell=False,
                                                 stdin=slaveTTY,
                                                 stdout=slaveTTY,
                                                 stderr=slaveTTY,
                                                 )
```

Using this returned tuple, I was able to perform `select.select([masterPTY],[],[])` and `os.read(masterPTY, 1024)` as needed, and I wrote to the master-pty with a function that is very similar to a private method in the pty module source:

```
def write_all(masterPTY, data):
    """Successively write all of data into a file-descriptor."""
    while data:
        chars_written = os.write(masterPTY, data)
        data = data[chars_written:]
    return data
```

Thanks to all for the good solutions.  Hope this example helps someone else.  :)