# python popen doesnt print stdout

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

i am trying to run a command racadam from dell(its a command line tool), into a subprocess.popen.

but I cant get back the stdout, or the stderr.   this is what I am doing.

```
prog = "C:\Program Files\Dell\SysMgt\\rac5\\racadm.exe"
pp = subprocess.Popen(prog, shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
pp.communicate()
print pp.communicate()

print pp.communicate()[0]
print pp.communicate()[1]

print pp.stdout.readlines()
print pp.stderr.readlines()

out, err = pp.communicate()
print out
print err
```

and  I just get

```
('', '')


[]
[]
```

when it should be printing the help with what arguments do what.

the funny thing is I can see that program terminal opening, printing some lines and then close super super fast.  so I know that the program is running  I just cant get the information back to python =(   may I bee missing some steps? or is there a hidden trick?

thanks guys.

Comment: what is prog and why are you using `shell=True`

Comment: tdout insert eat the "s" , to run it in the shell and be able to get the information back,  the tutorials that I read all use shell=True. if I do False I get WindowsError: [Error 740] The requested operation requires elevation

Comment: I think you are missing some double backslashes. After c:, After Files, After Dell. Print it out after assignment just to make sure.

Comment: did,  I do get C:\Program Files\Dell\SysMgt\rac5\racadm.exe  and the console runs fine, it evens open the console super fast and then it close so its grabing the right .exe file.

Comment: Since racadm.exe is a program that expects a tty, you might be interested in reading this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14941749/cannot-start-two-interactive-shells-using-popen . You may be having issues with the tty.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have actually written `tdout` instead of `stdout` while running your code

Try this

```
pp = subprocess.Popen(prog, shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = pp.communicate()
if pp.returncode == 0:
   final = out
else:
   final = err

print "Final output/Error is "+final
```

Comment: thanks.  I did try It and this is what I got. Final output/Error is 

0   is like there is nothing in the string, like ""

Comment: what is the output of `prog` when you run it directly?

Comment: http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/systems-management/w/wiki/3205.racadm-command-line-interface-for-drac should look something like in the images.    and my return code  say None  =(

Comment: I use the .wait()    after now I get the return code as 0